# Identify this user agent - claims to be IE7 on Windows 7

Tags: email, user-agent

We have a tracking pixel in one of our emails and our the most frequent user agent is this strange one:

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
```

If you enter this into [user-agent.info](http://user-agent-string.info/parse?Fuas=Mozilla/4.0%20%28compatible;%20MSIE%207.0;%20Windows%20NT%206.1;%20WOW64;%20Trident/4.0;%20SLCC2;%20.NET%20CLR%202.0.50727;%20.NET%20CLR%203.5.30729;%20.NET%20CLR%203.0.30729;%20.NET4.0C;%20.NET4.0E%29&test=9431&action=analyze) you will see that it claims to be Windows 7 (Windows NT 6.1) but at the same time IE 7, which [isn't available for this OS version](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/installing-ie7-on-windows-7-we-use-a-site-that/a414b7dc-d8da-4668-95e9-7574af7af3bc).

Since this is an email I'm guessing that it could be some Microsoft email program (Windows Mail, Outlook Express?) that is embedding an IE7 engine.

Does anyone know more?

PS: I'm aware that user agents are easily spoofed but that would have to be a pretty determined troll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be IE9 running in IE7 compatibility view, although I can't imagine that being "the most frequent user agent".

Like you say, this is most probably a (Windows) email client. Email clients are quite archaic in their rendering abilities, so IE7 is no surprise - in fact I thought later versions of Office (2007+) went further backwards and used the rendering engine from Word?

The first part would seem to be consistent with [Outlook 2007](http://user-agent-string.info/list-of-ua/browser-detail?browser=Outlook%202007), [Outlook 2010](http://user-agent-string.info/list-of-ua/browser-detail?browser=Outlook%202010) and [Outlook 2013](http://user-agent-string.info/list-of-ua/browser-detail?browser=Outlook+2013). However, these user agents usually identify themselves as being "MSOffice" or "Microsoft Outlook" respectively.

Outlook Express / [Windows Live Mail](http://user-agent-string.info/list-of-ua/browser-detail?browser=Windows+Live+Mail) would seem to identify themselves as "Outlook-Express".

However, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742443/how-to-tell-the-difference-between-user-agent-of-outlook-2003or-earlier-and-ie) (unanswered) on StackOverflow is asking the question of how to tell the difference between Outlook 2003 (and earlier) and a regular IE browser - since the two look very similar.

My best guess therefore is that your user agent string is from **Outlook 2003** (which I imagine is still a popular version). However, the niggling problem with this is that MSIE 7 only first appeared around 2005/6. It's hard to imagine that Microsoft would have looked ahead this far! If it is Outlook 2003 then I can only assume that various updates (perhaps to IE/Trident) will have updated the UA string also?

Comment: You are right. I ran a test in Litmus and found out that Outlook 2003 indeed identifies itself as IE7.